# Является ли Visual Studio СУБД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, visual-studio

Разрабатываю приложение в Visual Studio 2013 с локальной базой данных. Создание и редактирование таблиц и полей, баз данных производится прямо в самой студии. Получается, Visual Studio - это еще и СУБД?

Comment: Нет, Visual Studio взаимодействует с субд.

Comment: Я специально не устанавливал никаких СУБД. Может быть, что вместе со студией какая-нибудь СУБД устанавливается?

Comment: Посмотрите в списке установленных программ. С 2013 студией с десяток компонентов для MS SQL идет.

Comment: Да, оказывается установлен Microsoft SQL Server Compact. Наверное с ним студия и взаимодейсствует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строго говоря, СУБД (DBMS) - это не одна программа. Это совокупность программных средств. Поэтому вопрос "является ли Visual Studio СУБД" не имеет смысла. Это примерно как спросить "является ли игра сапер операционной системой - ведь с ее помощью можно выполнять часть стандартных функций Windows".

Более того - из определения следует, что любая утилита, которую вы используете для управления базой данных (в том числе и клиентские библиотеки System.Data) - автоматически становится частью СУБД в широком смысле этого слова.

Максимум что можно корректно спросить - является ли MS Visual Studio частью стандартного набора утилит СУБД MS SQL Server.

Но и тут нет однозначного ответа - Visual Studio, о котором вы говорите в вопросе - это оболочка для разработки сразу для нескольких языков и платформ. Поэтому, формально, она не полностью входит в СУБД SQL Server.

Но вот загвоздка в том, что SQL Server Management Studio, которая ну уж точно входит в СУБД SQL Server, уже лет 5 как просто адаптированная версия Visual Studio, из которой выброшена поддержка всех остальных языков. Если из не-СУБД выбросить что-то, она может стать СУБД? :)

На самом деле термин СУБД появился в древние времена, когда IDE еще не было, и о тесной интеграции между текстовым редактором, отладчиком и движком баз данных никто не помышлял. И можно было провести четкие границы. А сейчас можно просто не обращать на эти границы внимания.

Answer (score 1):

СУБД ее назвать нельзя, студия лишь позволяет выполнять некоторые манипуляции с объектами из БД, что иногда может быть удобным и не более, например, чтобы не запускать Sql Server Management Studio. Но вот полноценно работать с БД, используя Visual Studio вы не сможете.

Рекомендую Вам ознакомиться:

[Что такое IDE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

[Что такое СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Это даст Вам небольшое представление о данных понятиях.

Comment: Спасибо. А вот Sql Server Management Studio - это и есть СУБД? Или, в данном случае, СУБД - Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio - СУБД. Visual Studio - IDE.

Comment: @sp7 ну вообще-то Sql Server Management Studio - тоже не СУБД, а всего лишь инструмент, обеспечивающий "человекопонятный" интерфейс работы с MS Sql